# Rails Contact form within Static Controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, contact-form

I'm trying to add a Contact Form to an existing application and trying to follow a simple tutorial such as:

http://matharvard.ca/posts/2011/aug/22/contact-form-in-rails-3/

The tutorials all have the Contact Form generate their own controller, but the application I'm working on has the contact page setup within a static controller like this:

```
class StaticController < ApplicationController

  def about
  end

  def contact
  end

  def faq
  end

end
```

Is there a way to implement a contact form in this way or should I just pull out the contact page into its own controller?

Answer (score 0):

You'll probably want to separate them out.
Easiest way is probably this:

http://everydayrails.com/2011/09/07/rails-contact-form.html

based on the Mailform gem
https://github.com/plataformatec/mail_form

If you really don't want to use any logic at all, you could make a basic formin html with a mailto:,

http://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_form_mail

but that would require people to open their email client to send it. 
Hope that helps,